# Show just LV Size?

Tags: lvm

Is there a way to just show the sizes of all LV's on a volgroup? I have about 100 of them and it's a challenge to see which ones are the largest.

Answer (score 2):

The `lvs` tool will list the sizes of your LV's, along with some other information.
If you really only want the name and size of your LV's without any other information you can run `lvs -o lv_name,lv_size`